# Retrieving data from firebase using c# & ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve data from the firebase. this is the code I have:

```
private async void RetrieveTicket()
        {
            client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
            FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetTaskAsync("NewTicket/" + Ticket.TicketID.ToString());
            createTicketModel data = response.ResultAs<createTicketModel>();


            Ticket.User = data.User;
            Ticket.Department = data.Department;
            Ticket.Location = data.Location;
            Ticket.ContactNo = data.ContactNo;
            Ticket.Email = data.Email;
            Ticket.TicketDetails = data.TicketDetails;

            MessageBox.Show("Ticket details retrieved!");


        }
```

I have breakpoints through and it's receiving the data however it isn't displaying?

Comment: Where is code which displays the data?

Comment: <input type="text" asp-for="Ticket.TicketDetails" placeholder="Ticket Details" />
<button type="submit" asp-page-handler="RetrieveTicket" class="btn btn-outline-info" id="btnRetrieveTicket">Retrieve Ticket</button> - they all follow this format

Comment: @chlomg would you mind putting the code that displays the data in the question? It will make it easier for people to help you if they can see it all together.